# Сортировка массива объктов по значениям

Tags: javascript, массивы, строки, объекты, числа

Как отсортировать объект по цене oldUan
код ниже не правильно сортирует его

```
const sortedByPrice = () => {
 const sortPrice = products.slice()
  sortPrice.sort((a, b) => parseInt(b.price.newUan) - parseInt(a.price.newUan))
  return sortPrice;
  };

const products = [
        {
            ratingReviews: '264 отзыва',
            price: {
                oldUan: '4 333 грн',
                newUan: '3 799 грн',
            },
            name: 'Motorola MOTO G4 (XT1622) Black',
        }, {
            ratingReviews: '1355 отзывов',
            price: '4 999 грн',
            name: 'Samsung Galaxy J7 J700H/DS Black + карта памяти 16гб + чехол + защитное стекло!',
        }, {
            ratingReviews: '426 отзывов',
            price: '5 199 грн',
            name: 'Samsung Galaxy J5 (2016) J510H/DS Black + защитное стекло + чехол!',
        }, {
            ratingReviews: '403 отзыва',
            price: '4 349 грн',
            name: 'Xiaomi Redmi Note 4X 3/32GB Black',
        }, {
            ratingReviews: '488 отзывов',
            price: '6 199 грн',
            name: 'Samsung Galaxy J7 (2016) J710F/DS Gold + защитное стекло + чехол!',
        }, {
            ratingReviews: '198 отзывов',
            price: {
                oldUan: '3 495 грн',
                newUan: '2 995 грн',
            },
            name: 'Lenovo K5 (A6020a40) Silver',
        }, {
            ratingReviews: '352 отзыва',
            price: {
                oldUan: '9 799 грн',
                newUan: '7 999 грн',
            },
    ]
```

Answer (score 3):

// Очистить число от всех лишних элементов

```js
const price = '4 333 грн'
console.log(
  Number.parseInt(
    price.replace(/[^0-9]/g, '')
  )
)
```